# how local service is running in MainThread without affecting UI operations

Tags: android, android-service

I am lagging in basic android concept, 
    As per the documentation Service is running in MainThread. and Activity(UI) also running in same thread. In what way MainThread in the android application is running both components code (Service and Activity) paralelly. How android is handling this as local Service is not a separate process. Please give me detailed explanation or any specific links

Comment: I'm sure you've already visit the official page: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html I think you want to know something more... Do you want to know how Android framweork manage the service code inside the main thread? Can you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: @Seraphim's host, Yes exactly how service code managing without affecting the Activity(UI), making it feel like they both are running as separate individual threads. even though they both are running in same thread.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice most, if not all of the "main UI thread" methods you write, are callbacks -- they are not running any single main loop, but rather are called when needed, to perform bried tasks (ie: change UI).  There is clearly an android main loop that is listening and trigerring these methods.

That same android main loop sometimes also runs `Services` and `Handler` code.

As a result, basic simple `Services` should not kick off extended work loops, as that would prevent focus getting back to the UI methods.

Finally, if a UI method (or `Service` or `Handler`) starts doing a lot of work, the android main loop will trigger an Application Not Responding (ANR) to kill the app.